# xmpp with otr chat server and client

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, off-the-record-messaging

I have a lab for class and I am suppose to implement a chat app that implements otr.  There are a lot of tutorials that show how to add a otr plugin to give a current chat client otr functionality. However I would like to create as much of it from scratch as possible.  I want to use a raspberry pi as a xmpp server and connect clients to that server.  I am going to use a library like JSQMessagesViewController(iOS) or Applozic-Android-SDK(android) to create the chat framework.  But I want to be able to use otr to encrypt and authentication.
How is the best way to implement this? Can someone please point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Off the record messaging. otr.im

Comment: And what should that be?

Comment: I flagged this question as too broad because it is not a question that has a single clear answer. Maybe it should be moved to https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ? On the topic itself, I'd recommend [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) and the [PhoneGap build service](https://build.phonegap.com/) as a high-level cross-platform development framework as they support both iOS and Android from a single code base. You'd be writing JavaScript code, but I'm not sure whether there are any libraries for OTR out there.

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement OTR at client side?